# Injection of one instance to several beans

Tags: java, spring

There is one solution:

```
    <bean name="1" class="My1" />

<bean name="2" class="My2" scope="prototype">
    <property name="field1" ref="1">
</bean>

<bean name="3" class="My3" scope="prototype">
    <property name="field1" ref="1">
</bean>
```

But I don't want to do that. I don't want that bean "1" is accessible everywhere in the application and Spring controls it. I only want that bean "2" and "3" get the same instance. Can I achieve that? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the issue is.  By default, Spring beans are singletons.  So in your example, `2` and `3` already have the same instance of `1`.  The Spring-controlled instance of `1` is not really "accessible everywhere in the application", it's only accessible where it's been injected.

Comment: yeah. But now, I can get an ApplicationContext everywhere in my application and get this object by name

Comment: @itun Only if it's the same `ApplicationContext`.  I'm still not really sure what the issue is.  If you want spring-managed beans, then they need to be available in the context, otherwise they couldn't be used by the objects that need them.  If you *don't* want spring-managed beans, then make `1` a singleton.

Comment: The problem is that when beans "2" and "3" will be requested again I don't need the same bean "1", but I still need that their properties get the same instance of bean "1"

Comment: @itun Why is it a problem that `1` will be the same no matter how many times you call `2` or `3`?  Can you explain your situation in full?  Add it to the original question so that it will be clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is a full situation. The question is can I do that by spring?

Comment: Well, then the short answer is no.  Spring beans are designed to either be singletons or *not* singletons, but not a hybrid.  Singleton's lifespans are managed by Spring and--as far as I am aware--always last from instantiation to application close. If a bean is not a singleton then a new instance is created each time it's required, so `2` and `3` would never have the same instance of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't specify the bean "1" in the xml explicitely and just create its object in the controller first request and then put that in your session so that it can be accessible in the whole application with same instance. And you can access it in only the controller you want.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.